# Resolution problem ubuntu

Tags: display-resolution, screen, hardware, window, framerate

When I open a new window, this weird gaps appear on my screen. When I drag and move the window then it turns to normal. This happens every time I open a new window and move the mouse cursor over it. It is very annoying. What can I do about this?

Gaps:

[image]

Hardware info:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the Nvidia drivers? Which version?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the nvidia-driver-470-server. I have tried all versions but the problem persists.

Comment: Trying all version typically ends up in a serious mess. Better to start over by removing/purging ALL Nvidia drivers and then install ONLY the recommended version which in your case is indeed 470 but no server.

Comment: The problem persist after deleting/purging and reinstall.

Comment: Have you tested it - successfully - in Windows? The reason for this question is because hardware failure is a possibility.

Comment: Yes, I run dual boot with windows and there I have no problems with the same hardware. With the previous version of Ubuntu there were also no issues. It is since I have installed 20.04.3.